# JQplot with two different scales for same data (Meters and Feet)

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a requirement to show data on a line **jqPlot** with two different scales (meters and feet).  I have multiple lines/data sets on the same plot and also have a **jQuery toggle** which will switch the data sets displayed in the **jqPlot**.

I would like to have feet on one side and meters on the right side; however, the only way I can see to do this is to set the `min, max, and numTicks` for each **y-axis** and have the data associated with one scale (feet).

Is there a better way to have a set of data show with two separate scales?

`data1 = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]];` --In feet

Need left axis to be feet showing data1
Need right axis to show each **gridMark** in meters.

I have been marking left **y-axis** as `min: 0, max: 9, numTicks: 9`.
And right **y2axis** as `min:0, max: 2.74, numTicks: 9`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood..you could do this: (The trick is hide meters..)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var feet=[2052, 2205, 1910, 2085, 2261,  1714,  3123];
//transform values to meters...(I put some examples values..)
var meters=[2121, 32323, 65656, 21212, 32323,  54544,  31230];



var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [meters, feet], {
  title:'Meters and Feet',
 axes:{

      yaxis:{  
        autoscale:true,
        label: "feet"
      },  
      y2axis:{
        autoscale:true, 
        tickOptions:{showGridline:false},
        label: "meters"
      }

  },
    series:[{lineWidth:4, showLine: false, showMarker:false}, {yaxis:'y2axis'}]
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pabloker/aJnE3/1/

Comment: This does not work because I have different data sets that will be changed via toggle and the axes will change at that time.  I am showing data over years.

Comment: Well..I think that I didn't understand the problem. Could you include some graph, image, jsfiddle or something to figure out what do you need?